# WebService with dependency on callbacks

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, delegates

I have a WCF webservice and its getting data from a some client. The client has events such that when data is ready the event handler is called. I have trouble in coming up with a design to wrap this invocation in synchronous way so that I can expose it as a web-service.

Comment: your question is not very clear ...

Comment: plz add some code. what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by using aysn programming model with ManualResetEvent.